# SQL unpivot & insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the lack of info -- SQL Server 2008.

I'm struggling to get a couple of column values from table A into a new row in table B for each row in A where a column isn't null.

Table A's structure is as:

```
UserID | ClientUserID | ClientSessionID | [and a load of other irrelevant columns)
```

Table B:

```
UserID | Name | Value
```

I want to create rows in table B for each non-null ClientUserID or ClientSessionID  in A - using the column name as B's "Name", and column value as "B's Value".

I'm struggling to write my "unpivot" statement - just getting the syntax correct! I'm trying to follow along with some samples but can't

Here's my SQL query so far - any further help would be appreciated (just getting this SELECT is frustrating me, let alone doing the insert!)

```
SELECT UserID, ClientUserID, ClientSessionID FROM websiteuser WHERE ClientSessionID IS NOT null
```

This gives me the rows that I need to perform actions upon -- but I just can't get the syntax correct for UNPIVOTing this data and turning it into my insert.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What is the error you are getting for your version of unpivot?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot records in this fashion by using UNION to get each new row:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (UserID, Name, Value)
SELECT UserID, 'ClientUserID' AS Name, ClientUserID AS Value
FROM TableA
WHERE ClientUserID IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT UserID, 'ClientSessionID' AS Name, ClientSessionID AS Value
FROM TableA
WHERE ClientSessionID IS NOT NULL
```

I am using `UNION ALL` in this case as `UNION` implies a `DISTINCT` operation across the entire set, which should normally be unnecessary when pivoting unique records.

If your ClientUserID and ClientSessionID columns are not the same datatype, you may have to cast one or both to the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim - I was pretty hung up that using Unpivot was the way to solve this. Your query works excellently - thanks again :)